# SQL Remove Last Character if it is "-"

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to remove last character in a row but if the last character is "-" .

For example my row looks like this:

```
hello-world

today-is-monday-
```

It should be like this:

```
hello-world

today-is-monday
```

How can i do that in SQL ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `trim()` function as

```
mysql> select trim( trailing '-' from 'hello-');
+-----------------------------------+
| trim( trailing '-' from 'hello-') |
+-----------------------------------+
| hello                             |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select trim( trailing '-' from 'hello');
+----------------------------------+
| trim( trailing '-' from 'hello') |
+----------------------------------+
| hello                            |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

So in the query replace the hard coded `hello-` with your column name.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean UPDATE the table then this

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = SUBSTRING(field, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(field) - 1) 
WHERE field LIKE '%-'
```

If you mean you want to edit the output but not the data in the table then this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN field LIKE '%-' 
THEN SUBSTRING(field, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(field) - 1) 
ELSE field 
END AS field
```

Answer (score 0):

follow the code snipet
DECLARE

```
 a_msg VARCHAR2(4000);
 b_msg varchar2(100);
 BEGIN
 a_msg := '1,2,3,4,';
 b_msg := substr(a_msg,1,length(a_msg)-1);
 Dbms_Output.Put_line('b_msg:'||b_msg); 
 END ;
```

O/P : b_msg:1,2,3,4